# How to dynamically add new line to a label c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to print random dates in the format of Date-newline-Date-newline etc but dynamically add the dates from some c# code.
The current code I am using is shown below prints dates in one line with a space instead of a newline.

Here is my current code

```
private void WriteDates(int NumberOfDates)
{
    string dates = "";
    for(int i = 0 ; i < NumberOfDates; i++)
    {
       var print = RandomDay().ToShortDateString().ToString();
        dates += print + "\n";
    }
    LblDate.Text = dates;
}
```

Comment: Try `Environment.NewLine` instead of `"\n"`

Comment: `"\r\n"`, CR+LF

Comment: use StringBuilder for such operations and convert toString after the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\n is a special "line feed" character that doesn't create a line break in the browser's rendering of the HTML. It will create a line break in the HTML file itself, but the browser doesn't take this into consideration when it renders out the markup.

Look at the source of the page,(Chrome -> Developer tools) and you will see the line break within the Label element..

Try br tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid `for` loop where you can use LINQ:

```
private void WriteDates(int NumberOfDates)
{
    LblDate.Text = string.Join(string.Empty, 
        Enumerable.Range(0, NumberOfDates)
            .Select(n => $"{RandomDay().ToShortDateString()}<br />"));
}
```

Comment: Whats the benefit of using linq in this case?

Comment: @AndyStevens Less error-probe, much elegant (expressive).